# Local Database after publishing C#

Tags: c#, database, database-connection

i'm trying to make is so my program can have a local database after i have published it. Now i want it to work so i can install in on any computer so i have to change my connection string but i can't seem to figure out to what to change it to this is my connection string i have now

```
string constring = "Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = \"C:\\Barcode\\Application Files\\Barcode Scanning_1_0_0_0\\BarcodeDB.mdf\"; Integrated Security = True";
```

Before publishing i have went into applicationfiles and made sure that BarcodeDB.mdf is included but from what i've seen it changes to BarcodeDB.mdf.deploy after i've published it.

I've also went into Prerquisites and added

> SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB

When i try to run the published program or the debugger with the code i have now i get the error:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Barcode\Application Files\Barcode Scanning_1_0_0_0\BarcodeDB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share

I'm guessing i need to use:

> | DataDirectory |

But i'm new to all of this so i can't seem to figure it out how to use it even after searching for it so i would deeply appreciate it if someone could be kind to eiter explain how i chould be using DataDirectory or if i'm wrong and should be using something else.

And also sorry if i structured this question badly trying to get better at it

Best Regards Hannes.

Edit 1: Here is the code where i try to connect and using the database

```
        string constring = $"Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = \"{Application.ExecutablePath.ToString()}\\Application Files\\Barcode Scanning_1_0_0_0\\BarcodeDB.mdf\"; Integrated Security = True";
        string Query = "SELECT Name FROM Products ORDER BY EDate;";
        SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        SqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {

                string sName = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Name"));
                cbxProducts.Items.Add(sName);
                cbxProducts.Sorted = false;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        string constring = $"Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString() + "\\BarcodeDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

This fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

Ok I assume that your project is a Windows Forms or WPF project if it's not please tell me.

Your problem is that you are hard-coding a path to a database file which may not exist or your process can't have access to it's location. What you have found as `| DataDirectory |` is to use in web projects Web.Config file which will be mapped to `App_Data` folder.

In your case you have to build the connection string using your own applications executable path. Try this code:

```
//WPF:
string constring = $"Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = \"{System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location}\\BarcodeDB.mdf\"; Integrated Security = True";

//Windows Forms:
string constring = $"Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = \"{Application.ExecutablePath.ToString()}\\BarcodeDB.mdf\"; Integrated Security = True";
```

Comment: Yes i'm using windows forms sorry for not declaring that. When i use this code i still get                                                                                         
_"An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Barcode\Application Files\Barcode Scanning_1_0_0_0\BarcodeDB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share"_

Comment: Show me the part of code where you open a connection using this connection string.

Comment: added code to the question of where i use it, i use it in other places aswell but it should be the same code i need for every place